# Difference between 'as dynamic[]' and ToArray()

Tags: c#, performance, dynamic, ienumerable

I was refactoring some code and let ReSharper help me out a bit. I got this piece of code:

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> records = ...;
ScheduleTemplateInfo[] resultTemplateInfos = new ScheduleTemplateInfo[records.Count()];
```

Here he warned me that there might be a `Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable`. So I let ReSharper refactor and he gave me this:

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> records = ...;
dynamic[] recordsAsArray = records as dynamic[] ?? records.ToArray();
ScheduleTemplateInfo[] resultTemplateInfos = new ScheduleTemplateInfo[recordsAsArray.Length];
```

Now, I suppose that does look more efficient at first sight. However, I am curious about the second line that has been inserted.

What is the difference between casting records `as dynamic[]` and making records`.ToArray()`? Is one more efficient than the other? More foolproof?

Comment: `.ToArray()` creates a new array and then copies all the items. If `records` already is an array then that is work that doesn't need to be done, so they try to directly cast it to a `dynamic[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`records` starts as an `IEnumerable<dynamic>`.  This means it could actually be anything that implements `IEnumerable<dynamic>`, including an array.  It might instead be a `List<dynamic>`, or one of a dozen other collection types.

It wants to create `dynamic[]`.  If `records` already *happens to be* of type `dynamic[]`, the `records as dynamic[]` will cast it and return it.  If not, that particular expression will return `null`, leaving the null coalescing operator (`??`) to return the right hand side instead.

This right hand side runs the LINQ method `.ToArray()` on whatever type `records` happens to be, which will convert it to a `dynamic[]` and potentially involves a lot more work than the simple cast.

Depending on what's actually going on here, you might be able to change things a bit yourself - for instance if you know that the `...;` part *never* returns a `dynamic[]`, you may as well just have `records.ToArray()` without the cast check.